# Vert.x virtual thread per request

Tags: vert.x, virtual-threads

I am testing vert.x with virtual threads (java 21, vert.x 4.5.0).

I wonder how the `await` method is supposed to be used in the context of a web server and handlers specifically.

Say I have a basic server verticle like this:

```java
public class Server extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        try {
            Router router = Router.router(vertx);
            router.route("/health").handler(ctx -> {
                await(ctx.response().end());
            });

            vertx.createHttpServer()
                    .requestHandler(router)
                    .listen(8080);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new Server());
}
```

Now if I call the health endpoint the following error is printed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot be called on a Vert.x event-loop thread

Which makes sense, the await is blocking the event loop.

So my initial guess was to add `ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD` like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx.vertx().deployVerticle(new Server(),
                new DeploymentOptions()
                        .setThreadingModel(ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD));

        while (true) {
        }
    }
```

(note the required while true now because else the application exits immediately)

Now if I call /health the error is not printed anymore. But I am not sure if this does what I expect it to.

I would think that with this I am able to have 1 virtual thread per request, but I am not sure if this is what is actually happening, as there is no documentation about the virtual thread threading model.

So my question is: is this the correct way to start a server where handlers can freely await all futures? Does this start one virtual thread per request? Also, is there a way to get rid of the while true loop?

**Edit:** After receiving the initial detailed response, I tried to test this behavior, but found that it does not behave as expected:

I edited my handler to be blocking on purpose:

```java
router.route("/health").handler(ctx -> {
                System.out.println("Enter: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                await(vertx.executeBlocking(() -> {
                    System.out.println("Blocking: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    return null;
                }));
                System.out.println("Exit: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                await(ctx.response().end());
            });
```

Now if I do two concurrent requests I see the following printed:

Enter: vert.x-virtual-thread-2

Blocking: vert.x-virtual-thread-3

Exit: vert.x-virtual-thread-2

Enter: vert.x-virtual-thread-3

Blocking: vert.x-virtual-thread-5

Exit: vert.x-virtual-thread-3

And the requests are executed one after another, meaning my server is blocked! Is my way of sleeping in the handler maybe the problem?

Edit #2:

Setting `ordered` to false in `executeBlocking` resolves the issue. I am still not sure why I need to call executeBlocking at all in an virtual-thread based handler, as blocking the virtual thread of the handler should not block the server in my opinion. If anyone has an answer to this I would appreciate a comment, but I will resolve this issue for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD` is specified, then upon deployment and creation of `Vertx` instance the `Context` with `virtualThreaWorkerPool` will be created. This `WorkerPool` will use an `ExecutorService`/pool which is created with `ThreadFactory` which creates virtual threads; in fact `Vertx`'s static `VIRTUAL_THREAD_FACTORY` is created as `Thread.ofVirtual().factory()`.

So, your handler will be executed on a virtual thread -  one virtual thread per request - exactly as `ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD` promises. You could check it in the handler implementation

```
router.route("/health").handler(ctx -> {
    ...
    boolean virtual = Thread.currentThread().isVirtual(); // renders true
    ...
});
```

Your while(true) endless loop in the case of `ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD` is an unnecessary CPU hogging.

```
while (true) { // spurious wakeups
    synchronized (Server.class) {
        Server.class.wait();
    }
}
```

will serve the purpose better. Or, if we love to hate `synchronized`:

```
while (true) {
    LockSupport.park();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I wanted to test what you wrote (one vthread per request) and I can't seem to get it to work. I modified my handler to be blocking on purpose (see in my modified question). And now requests are not executed in parallel anymore (also see the output above). What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't the same thread behavior rendered when you use ordinary/non-virtual multithreading `ThreadingModel.WORKER`?  My experiment shows in this case the same threads' interleaving picture as you brought in your updated question. Thus, the problems seems to be somewhere in our orchestration of handlers, rather than in virtual nature of the worker threads.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. When I switch the implementation back to event loop threading model and make the handler use `onComplete` instead of `await`, then the two calls execute in parallel and the thread.sleep of one does not block the other. Does that mean you can't use executeBlocking using virtual threaded handlers?

Comment: No, I don't think that usage of `executeBlocking` is a cause. My point was different: sequential execution is not caused by the usage of virtual threads _themselves_, because with ordinary threads (`ThreadingModel.WORKER` mode) the situation is the same. Note that ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP is not "genuine", `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService`-based multithreading.  So, to use virtual threads (`ThreadingModel.VIRTUAL_THREAD` mode) we first may want to learn how to correctly use ordinary multithreading (`ThreadingModel.WORKER` mode).

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem: executeBlocking must be called with the "ordered: false" flag. I still wonder why I need executeBlocking at all though, as the handler should be it's own virtual thread already.

Comment: I should have said: Congrats! But I cannot because 1) I played with exactly this flag yesterday and failed to achieve parallelism 2)  no, absolutely not, to my understanding of web server ideology: there is no any obligation of using `executeBlocking `. Also, your handler may be not blocking at all and you still would want parallelism (For exactly that reason, I guess, default timeout on event loop is 2 sec, but on workers - 60 sec).
BTW, I failed to reproduce parallelism on event loop, like you wrote above. Maybe our understanding of it is slightly different. Anyway, Merry Christmas to you!

Comment: Revisited `executeBlocking` with  "ordered: false" flag and realized that it works, you are right! Something I've overlooked at first attempt.  `executeBlocking` with  "ordered: false" seems to be a right way to achieve parallelism. Interesting enough, this works for `ThreadingModel.EVENT_LOOP` mode as well. So, threading model affects `Future.await`, but not `executeBlocking`.
Good reason to update your question or add new answer with your finding, so that the solution won't be lost in a long list of comments.